# Unable to find NIB in bundle only after adding an object to CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, nib

This has been stumping me for a few hours and after looking through all kinds of related questions, I can't seem to figure out an answer.

I am getting a strange NSInternalInconsistencyException error.  The error states that it cannot load an NIB with the name **CountTableViewController**.  However, when I first run the app (in *both* simulator and physical device), I can segue to that view controller just fine.  It loads and looks just as it does in the **Main.storyboard** file.  Then, when I navigate back and activate another view controller that loads some test data into the Core Data Stack that I am using, things go very wrong.  Using breakpoints and console logs, I can see that the single object has been successfully added into the Core Data Stack.  But, when I click on the **CountTableViewController** again, the app crashes with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <FILEPATH> (loaded)' with name 
'CountTableViewController''
```

I have read through every related question I could find, here's a quick list of things I have already tried that were unsuccessful:

- Check spelling/case of related files and any place they are referenced

  - (CountTableViewController.swift, CountTableViewCell.swift, CountReuseCell [reuse id])
- Delete references to related files, re-drag into Xcode
- Delete references to Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard, re-drag into Xcode
- Verify that every file is listed correctly under 'Compile Sources' in 'Build Phases' of Project
- Verify that storyboards are listed correctly under 'Copy Bundle Resources' in 'Build Phases' of Project
- Rewrite as a totally new view controller from scratch (still got same error)

I'm *pretty* sure it's CoreData related since that seems to be the only difference between when the view controller does and does not work, but I'm pretty new to Swift and iOS dev, so I could be way off target.

I have the stack trace that I will post below.  I will try to post some concise parts of the code that I think will be helpful.  Thank you in advance for your help!

#### StackTrace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010721912b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102a78f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010728e245 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
3   UIKit                               0x00000001043fd098 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 501
4   UIKit                               0x00000001040b2687 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 590
5   UIKit                               0x0000000120c4f79d -[UITableViewAccessibility dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] + 147
6   UIKit                               0x00000001040b2b6b -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:] + 148
7   UIKit                               0x00000001040b2aa3 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 89
8   UIKit                               0x0000000120c4f8e0 -[UITableViewAccessibility dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 285
9   BSA Inventory Control               0x00000001018d35d6 _T021BSA_Inventory_Control24CountTableViewControllerC05tableF0So07UITableF4CellCSo0iF0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV12cellForRowAttF + 774
10  BSA Inventory Control               0x00000001018d3c4c _T021BSA_Inventory_Control24CountTableViewControllerC05tableF0So07UITableF4CellCSo0iF0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV12cellForRowAttFTo + 92
11  UIKit                               0x00000001040ce484 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 778
12  UIKit                               0x00000001040cea2a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
13  UIKit                               0x00000001040941f6 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3031
14  UIKit                               0x00000001040b62e6 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
15  UIKit                               0x000000010403ea6d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1439
```

#### CountTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class CountTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.shared
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext! = nil
    var counts: [Count] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        moc = coreDataStack.viewContext
        
        tableView.register(CountTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountReuseCell")
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CountTableViewController", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountReuseCell")
    }
    func reload() {
        counts = Count.items(for: moc, matching: nil, sortedBy: nil)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        reload()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return counts.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountReuseCell", for: indexPath) as? CountTableViewCell else  {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of CountTableViewCell")
        }
        let count = counts[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = count.name       
        return cell
    }
}
```

The **CountTableViewCell.swift** file is just a default Cocoa Touch Class with a subclass of UITableViewCell and a single outlet linking to the `nameLabel` in the storyboard.

A few quick afterthoughts... please let me know if there's any info you need that I didn't include here.  I'm using a Core Data Stack Class and an extension adapted by a professor in an iOS dev class I took a year ago that provides the easy to use `.items()` functionality... I can also post that if you think that's causing any issues.  This is so strange because I have another Core Data entity (Product instead of Count) using almost the exact same code that works perfectly.  I can't seem to figure out what is different about this scenario...

*Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b), iOS Version 11.2 (15C107)*

Comment: If you were to segue back and forth to CountTableViewController without the intermediate step where you create a managed object, does it crash?

Comment: @TomHarrington it does not crash when I move back and forth between the root menu and the CountTableVC.  It only crashes when the managed object has been created.  I believe that it has to do with the storyboard interface because I was able to create the CountTableVC completely programmatically and it works great!  I’m still stumped on the error but at least I have a work around right now.

Comment: Why are you registering the CountTableViewController nib with the tableView - shouldn’t it be a cell nib?  And why register the nib as well as the class?  Also, note that it is looking for a nib with that name, which is different from loading the CountTableViewController from the storyboard.  Also, I think CoreData is a red herring.  I suspect it is only relevant because adding an object causes the TV to have non-zero rows, and so it tries to create a cell, which causes the error.

Comment: @pbasdf Good question!  I reverted back to the old code to try this out.  I removed two lines that were trying to register the nib and class, leaving only one line to register the TableViewCell, and this got rid of the original exception!  I was getting an error trying to unwrap `nameLabel`, but that is likely because I had been messing around with deleting and readding links to try and troubleshoot.  Since I got the programatic code working, I'm just going to use that, but I agree, it seems the CoreData was a red herring.  The issue was with how I was registering the CustomCell.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to wrap things up and hopefully help someone in the future, the issue seems to have been in these lines within the **CountTableViewController.swift**:

```
tableView.register(CountTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountReuseCell")
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CountTableViewController", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountReuseCell")
```

As usual, it seems this was a mixture of reusing old code and copy/pasting.  It's strange that this code seems to work fine in almost an identical scenario with the `Product` entity in the same project.  Nevertheless, I removed the last two lines above, leaving me with only:

```
tableView.register(CountTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CountReuseCell")
```

Sure enough, the **NSInternalInconsistencyException** error was gone!

Last night, I was able to rewrite the **CountTableViewController** entirely programatically and it is working correctly, so I plan to use that for now.  However, it is good to know what was causing this error for the  future.

Thanks to @pbasdf for the comment/answer!

Comment: Why would you even register a controller as a cell?

Comment: @Sulthan honestly I have no clue.  I took an iOS dev course in college a year ago and I used one of our labs from class as a guide to set up this project.  That code is something I pulled from there. Now, after researching and learning what those lines are actually doing, I agree it makes no sense whatsoever.  Still not sure how it worked for us in those labs (but I did rerun them to make sure and it does work...).